# Adding a table of contents on the left side with HTML document in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r, knitr, r-markdown

Im trying to add a table of contents in a HTML document produced by Rmarkdown. First of all, I found [this answer](http://rpubs.com/stevepowell99/floating-css), which seems a easy way to do, adding a CSS file whit this code in the HTML file:

```
#TOC {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:210px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

But I would like to modify the CSS from the Rmarkdown. To solve the problem I found [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32352347/7654451), how to add custom CSS tags. But is not exactly what Im looking for, and dont know how to mix this to answers in a properly way.

My code look like this:

````
---
title: "R"
output: html_document
toc: yes
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r results="asis"}
cat("TOC {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:210px;
  line-height: 20px;
}")
```
````

I think Im missing something important. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the code of your [first answe](http://rpubs.com/stevepowell99/floating-css)r, you need to add these in your YAML header, but you need to be careful with the spaces:

```
title: "cssTest"
    output:
    html_document:
      css: custom.css
      toc: yes
```

Then, the css file should be an external css file. Out of your Rmd code. Here, it is a file in the same directory than your Rmd file, which is called `custom.css`.

Comment: So, is not possible to modify the .css from the Rmarkdown?

Comment: I don't know. You can try to `cat` with `file = custom.css`. This may work as knit first run the R code before running Pandoc for HTML code...

Answer (score 1):

Hmisc package is great and easy for this, just add the following to your startup chunk and run it. it will render in the html:

```
hidingTOC(
buttonLabel = "Contents",
levels = 3,
tocSide = c("right", "left"),
buttonSide = c("right", "left"),
posCollapse = c("margin", "top", "bottom"),
hidden = FALSE
)
```

tocSide specifies which side you want the TOC to be. for more specific documentation, here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf