# Custom CSS to rmarkdown chunk to change width of graph

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an rmarkdown document which output html. I have my own css styles that I use by adding it to the YAML header. I also want to control css of specific code chunks. I have a dashboard (3x2 grid of plots) that I want to have larger width than the main document.
I've found these two questions:
[Add a CSS class to single code chunks in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944197/add-a-css-class-to-single-code-chunks-in-rmarkdown)
[Adding custom CSS tags to an RMarkdown html document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291633/adding-custom-css-tags-to-an-rmarkdown-html-document)

But neither of them are working for me (or I didn't understand the answers). I want to change the width of a plot so it float into the margins e.g. width: 110%. I tried this:

````
```{r dash1, fig.height=16, fig.width=14, results="asis"}
cat("
<style>
    .toc-content {
        width: 110%;
    }
</style>
")


margin = theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,2), "cm"))

pl_1 <- list(g_1_kaupmattur, g_2_gallup, g_3_vnv, g_4_spa, g_5_ibud, g_6_swirlo)
grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(pl_1, "+", margin), ncol = 2)

```
````

This changed the whole document, not only the output of this particular chunk.
I also tried creating a new css style with `width: 110%` and adding it to the chunk option like this:

````
```{r dash1, fig.height=16, fig.width=14, class.source="dash_styles"}

margin = theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,1,2), "cm"))

pl_1 <- list(g_1_kaupmattur, g_2_gallup, g_3_vnv, g_4_spa, g_5_ibud, g_6_swirlo)
grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(pl_1, "+", margin), ncol = 2)

```
````

It didn't work either.

I would like the plot to extend to the margins as I "show" on the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: This requires to change the css, which might be a bit tedious. To see how this would work, you can use the inspector of your web browser and figure out why you get this. You'll realize that this is a matter of padding and margin. You can increase the width for the image but then you'll have to figure out how to align it properly.